# Compare node timestamp with MySQL timestamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typeorm

I have a `updated_at` column in my table with type timestamp. I am going to update it with node ISOstring whenever the API is called and return the same updated ISO string to the front end for further updates. But when the API is hit again with new `updated_at` value I compare the received updated-at value ISO string with the fetched `updated_at` value making a Select query prior to update. When I compare the `updated_at` values they are not the same. For example:

1. Update `updated_at` with node `ISO` string `2020-07-11T17:21:42.354Z`and send it to client.
2. For second update, client value is `2020-07-11T17:21:42.354Z`, but the value I get when fetched from the db is `2020-07-11T15:36:48.000Z`. Clearly, both are not the same.

The MySql timezone is set as UTC.

Code is as follows:

```
async save(giData: any) {
    try {
      await this.validateAccess(giData);
      let validatedData = await this.validate(giData);
      let profileData: any = await this.profileRepo.save(validatedData);
      return profileData;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

async validate(item) {
   let previousItem = await this.profileRepo.findOne(item.id);

      if (
        item.updatedAt &&
        previousItem.updatedAt.toISOString() !=
        new Date(item.updatedAt).toISOString()
      )
        throw 'Record already updated';
      item.updatedAt = new Date().toISOString();
      return item;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's no obvious relation between the timestamp you sent, and the one you get back, so it's not a timezone issue. My guess is that there is something incorrect with your code, so you should share it.

Comment: Avoid using `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL. This data type is flaky will run out of values in 2038.